# Are there plans to turn The Eyre Affair into a movie?

Tags: jasper-fforde

I’ve been thinking about a movie adaptation of Jasper Fforde’s *The Eyre Affair* and the rest of the *Thursday Next* series.

Is there any official comment about such a movie?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this interview](http://www.januarymagazine.com/profiles/fforde.html) with Jasper Fforde, there are presently no plans to do a movie adapatation. This is largely due to his refusal (or possibility his inability) to sell the rights to a movie studio with sufficient clout to do justice to the novels he's written.

> **Q.** **Who plays Thursday Next in your ideal movie version?**
>
> **Fforde:** *Me* [Laughs] *I don't know ... **I won't sell the rights.** I don't know whether it's
>   filmable. I'd like to have a go at doing it. If it was the actress,
>   you'd have to have an unknown, probably from theater because no one is
>   famous from theater. The point with the Thursday Next books is you
>   have to suspend all disbelief so you would need an extremely talented
>   unknown. That would be cheaper, too.*

---

The other issue is presumably that while it's possible to cleverly reference a wide variety of well known films in *written format* without running foul of their rights-holders, doing so in film would be next to impossible, leaving the studio with the unenviable choice of making the film either very very expensive to make, or requiring them to ditch a large amount of the source material.